# I am getting NoClassDefFound error when running with listeners included and getting passed without listeners

Tags: java, testng

Getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error when running xml file using
>   testng.
>   Error details: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class com.listeners.ExtentTestManager at
>   com.listeners.Listeners.onTestFailure(Listeners.java:56)

I am using testng version 6.9.10 in pom.xml.

Hi, I am getting this error when I use listeners in my xml file. If I remove listeners and run the xml file, it is working. Please let me know if anything wrong with ExtentTestManager class or the dependencies. I am unable to add code in stackoverflow, so I have attached in this link: [selenium99.com/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror](https://selenium99.com/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) Pls check.

Comment: Do you own the `listeners.com` domain?

Answer (score -1):

You can try maven update project in eclipse after that use clean install, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Basically 
`NoClassDefFoundError` can occur for multiple reasons like

`ClassNotFoundException` -- .class not found for that referenced class irrespective of whether it is available at compile time or not(i.e base/child class).
Class file located, but Exception raised while initializing static variables
Class file located, Exception raised while initializing static blocks

But in this case it looks like you are missing some dependency in the building.

you can try cleaning whole project and build again.

If it's a eclipse project

```
mvn clean eclipse:eclipse

mvn clean package
```

try above commands

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is a linkage error. `ClassNotFoundException` is a reflective operation exception. How are the two related?